# PsExec C# Doesn't work after changing from iis Express To iis Local

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, psexec

i used this code to install apps on remote machine but after changing the iis it returns in the standard error that there is an "Invalid identifier" (*"Descripteur non valide*" as my pc is in French)

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"psexec";
string update = "REINSTALLMODE=vomus";
if (isupdate)
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + Poste.Name + " -h  -u " + Poste.AdminName 
             + " -p " + Poste.AdminPassword + " msiexec /i " 
             + @"\\Bchir\FileRepository\"+ FileName + " TARGETDIR=" 
             + TargetPath + " /quiet " + update;

p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + Poste.Name + " -h  -u " 
          + Poste.AdminName + " -p " + Poste.AdminPassword 
          + " msiexec /i " + @"\\BCHIR\FileRepository\" + FileName  
          + " TARGETDIR=" + TargetPath;

p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.Start();
```

this is the StandardOutput
[image: StandardOutput]

and this is the StandardError
[image: StandardError]

Comment: Does the account IIS is running under have the required permissions to perform this task?

Comment: how can check that i'm a  newbie

Comment: If the IIS Application Pool account is the default one, it won't have permission to access any files or directories outside wwwroot.

Comment: how can i change it